# How to install Zulucrypt in Ubuntu!

Tags: software-installation

Hi everybody, I want to know how to install Zulucrypt in Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 3):

Add the PPA `ppa:hda-me/zulucrypt` via

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:hda-me/zulucrypt
sudo apt-get update
```

and install

```
sudo apt-get install zulucrypt-cli zulucrypt-gui
```

for the GUI and the CLI version.

Comment: For ubuntu 18 and 19, you don't need to add the ppa anymore. zulucrypt is part of 'universe': https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/eoan/zulucrypt

Comment: Currently the PPA and 'universe' have version 5.4 for Ubuntu 18.04, but version 6.0 is available via the compiled binaries in github - as suggested in the answer by @tom-mercer

Answer (score 2):

Go to
https://github.com/mhogomchungu/zuluCrypt/releases/

And select your release package.

You can read the README, which will say:

extract the directory full of .debs, open a terminal, cd to the directory, and run

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

For 17.10, https://github.com/mhogomchungu/zuluCrypt/releases/download/5.2.0/zuluCrypt-5.2.0-ubuntu-17.10-Artful_Aardvark.tar.xz

For 17.04
https://github.com/mhogomchungu/zuluCrypt/releases/download/5.2.0/zuluCrypt-5.2.0-ubuntu-17.04-Zesty_Zapus.tar.xz

Answer (score 0):

run command :

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/hda-me/zulucrypt/ubuntu trusty main ' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/zulucrypt.list"
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install zulucrypt-gui
```

this ppa have packages `libzulucrypt-dev` `zulucrypt-cli` `zulucrypt-gui`.  if you want to install `cli` package.

```
sudo apt-get install zulucrypt-cli
```

this command will automatically install it dependency packages `libcryptsetup4` `libzulucrypt1`

press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and search for `zuluCrypt`.
it is tested on `Ubuntu 14.04`.

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer is now way out-of-date, despite this question being the #1 Google result for installing zuluCrypt on Ubuntu.

It's far, far better to go here, download the latest version, you can get a .deb file for your system.

https://github.com/mhogomchungu/zuluCrypt

Comment: This is good for 16.04, 16.10, and 17.04.

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be a PPA for this:

https://launchpad.net/~hda-me/+archive/ubuntu/zulucrypt